# Xpath not function

Tags: xml, xpath

Trying to pull some data from TfL status feed -

```
<LineStatus ID="6" StatusDetails="Minor delays between Acton Town and Heathrow/Uxbridge due to an earlier faulty train at Holborn. GOOD SERVICE on the rest of the line.">
<BranchDisruptions>
  <BranchDisruption>
    <StationTo ID="244" Name="Uxbridge"/>
    <StationFrom ID="1" Name="Acton Town"/>
    <Status ID="MD" CssClass="GoodService" Description="Minor Delays" IsActive="true">
      <StatusType ID="1" Description="Line"/>
    </Status>
  </BranchDisruption>
  <BranchDisruption>
    <StationTo ID="284" Name="Heathrow Terminal 5"/>
    <StationFrom ID="1" Name="Acton Town"/>
    <Status ID="MD" CssClass="GoodService" Description="Minor Delays" IsActive="true">
      <StatusType ID="1" Description="Line"/>
    </Status>
  </BranchDisruption>
</BranchDisruptions>
```

Simply using xpath=//@Name works to pull the data out of the Name element in our signage software but I don't want the node to show up if it's under the `<BranchDisruption>` parent. Have tried lots of combinations along the lines of,

```
xpath=//@Name[not(ancestor::BranchDisruption)]
```

but no luck. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There is no element with attribute `Name` under the parent

Comment: Write exactly what elements you want to select from the example

Comment: Hi splash58, sorry reading that back I left some info out. Where you have Name="Uxbridge", this is working for me (the code pulls the 'Uxbridge' out but I don't want it to work if it's under the <BranchDisruption> tag (there was a lot more code on the page I copied this from).

Comment: Do you not want to select the 1 item after <BranchDisruption> ?

Comment: Yes. There's lot of other code on the page where this works, it's only when under <BranchDisruption> I don't want it to work. Thank you.

Comment: It is still unclear what you are asking. Show a [complete, minimal, well-formed example of the XML input document](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and _show_ (instead of describing) which nodes you would like to select from the document.

Comment: Maybe you need `//*[position()>1]/@Name`

Comment: @SimonCB One question : Are you sure that elements of type which have `Name` attributes  like `<StationTo ID="244" Name="Uxbridge"/>` are immediate children of `BranchDisruption`  always ?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Svasa's answer below does the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the assumption that the elements which have attributes `Name` are immediate children of `BranchDisruption` always, I see the following xpath works :

`//@Name/parent::*/parent::*[not(name()='BranchDisruption')]/*/@Name`

Test xpath on below xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LineStatus ID="6" StatusDetails="Minor delays between Acton Town and Heathrow/Uxbridge due to an earlier faulty train at Holborn. GOOD SERVICE on the rest of the line.">
<BranchDisruptions>
  <BranchDisruption>
    <StationTo ID="244" Name="Uxbridge"/>
    <StationFrom ID="1" Name="Acton Town"/>
    <Status ID="MD" CssClass="GoodService" Description="Minor Delays" IsActive="true">
      <StatusType ID="1" Description="Line"/>
    </Status>
  </BranchDisruption>
  <BranchDisruption>
    <StationTo ID="284" Name="Heathrow Terminal 5"/>
    <StationFrom ID="1" Name="Acton Town"/>
    <Status ID="MD" CssClass="GoodService" Description="Minor Delays" IsActive="true">
      <StatusType ID="1" Description="Line"/>
    </Status>
  </BranchDisruption>
<Non-BranchDisruption>
    <StationTo ID="284" Name="Heathrow Terminal 6"/>
    <StationFrom ID="1" Name="Acton Town 7"/>
    <Status ID="MD" CssClass="GoodService" Description="Minor Delays" IsActive="true">
      <StatusType ID="1" Description="Line"/>
    </Status>
  </Non-BranchDisruption>
</BranchDisruptions>
</LineStatus>
```

It will give :

`Attribute='Name="Heathrow Terminal 6"'
Attribute='Name="Acton Town 7"'`

Comment: Amazing. Thank you for your help. This has worked. Much appreciated.